# How long was the kingdom under the spell before Belle arrived?

Tags: plot-explanation, beauty-and-the-beast

In the classic story, [*Beauty and the Beast*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101414/), the objects and the Beast always seem to say that they have been there for a *looooong* time. Belle showed up at the end of who knows how long. How long was the kingdom and the beast under the spell from the enchantress before Belle arrived? That is my question.

Comment: It was up and running *once upon a time* =)

Comment: Are you asking the specific date on which the Beast and his castle were enchanted? Or just how long they were enchanted?

Comment: I tried to put your question into a context that the community could better understand.  If this is not the question that you intended to ask, please feel free to roll back the edit.  Also, now that it should be a little more clear, I voted to reopen your question as well.  Thank you for your contribution :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 10 Years

In the film Lumiere answers this when he say's during the singing of *Be Our Guest*

> "Ten years we've been rusting..."

This can be seen at about 1:54 in the below clip.

This is an answer courtesy of the question posed here

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13833/was-prince-adam-really-11-when-he-was-transformed